# Batch-import and auto-indexing

Tags: neo4j

I'm using batch-import to load a very small graph (5 nodes; 3 rels) into `neo4j 2.0`.

I believe all the auto-indexing properties are set right in `neo4j.properties`:

```
node_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=name,age
```

Here is what I did:

```
1. neo4j stop
2. batch-import
3. neo4j start
4. query: START r=node:node_auto_index(name="Rana") return r
```

I got the following Cypher error
Index `node_auto_index` does not exist

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the index creation before you query the index. The easy way to do that is something like:

```
create (n {name:"a",age:"a"}) delete n;
```

You only need to do this once--once the index is created it won't give you that error.

Comment: Thanks. However, now it is reporting "Returned 0 rows. Query took 196ms". Yet the data is actually in there. Anything wrong?

Comment: If the index was not created, that means it didn't have any data in it. Enabling auto-indexing doesn't automatically go initialize the index (unfortunately). You can do something like this (don't do it on a huge graph without doing limit/skip): `start n=node(*) set n.name=n.name, n.age=n.age;`

Comment: The property 'name' does not exist on Node[0]
I guess I need to skip Node[0]? How?

Comment: With the auto_index enabled, running individual cypher command does index data properly.
What I had above seems specific to batch-import. Is there an elegant way to handle it, other than manually triggering the indexing?

Comment: You can tell the batch importer to create an index called node_auto_index, with the fields you want to index. This question was asked on the forums within the last couple of weeks. To skip node[0], you can do `where id(n) <> 0` in the cypher command. Or you can do `where has(n.name) and has(n.age)`.